# Cannot edit CSV file within a Powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, csv, parallel-processing, workflow

I am trying to change the value of an element in a CSV file WITHIN A WORKFLOW.

```
workflow Test-WrkFlw{

    $students = Import-Csv C:\Users\user1\students.csv
    $students.Checked = "Yes"

}
Test-WrkFlw
```

However `$students.Checked = "Yes"` gives me an error:

> "This type of assignment is not supported. Only variable names (i.e.: $variable) may be used as the target of an assignment statement".

If I take those two lines out of the workflow statement the assignment works just fine. However I need this assignment in a workflow because I am trying to use it in a foreach -parallel loop, and parallel has to be in a workflow for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 $ErrorList = Import-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ";"
 foreach ($item in $ErrorList)
 {
    $item.checked="Yes"
 }

 $ErrorList | select checked, nom | Export-Csv  -Path C:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: My problem is that in my actual foreach loop is going to use the -parallel option. -parallel must be located inside a workflow. But when I put this assignment inside a workflow $item.checked will give me an error.